# How was Marienbad My Love written?

Tags: writing-process

I just googled through World's Longest Novel, and the one that seems to come up as an actual story novel (as opposed to things like The Blah Story by Nigel Tomm, which is apparently not an actual story) is Marienbad My Love. But there seem to be hints that its 17 million plus word count wasn't entirely written, but that big sections were lifted as long quotes from other works. Since it's about a science fiction film creator, it seems plausible, but I cannot find definite answers if this was the case.

Was Marienbad My Love partially written by lifting sections from other texts as quotes or the like?

Answer (score 2):

***Marienbad My Love* is made of cuts from other books, but some of them were by the same author.**

Straight from the horse's mouth at [the website of the book and author](http://www.marienbadmylove.com/):

> This multi-million-word, multi-volume work has been meticulously assembled through calculation and chance from fragments of pre-existing texts both written and appropriated by Mark Leach over the course of 30 years - "the movie," as Leach calls it, "of all my labors and all my inspirations."

As the author [said](http://www.marienbadmylove.com/diy-novel-kit.html):

> Writing is 
>   hard, but it’s not always easy to be a scissors-and-paste man, either.

He's also willing to give as well as take: he's lifted copyright protections on *Marienbad My Love* and [invited any other budding writers to plagiarise from it](http://www.marienbadmylove.com/diy-novel-kit.html). I'm not sure what this says about him, but he's also gleefully [copied on his website](http://www.marienbadmylove.com/comments.html) the speculations from internet forumgoers that he's mentally ill. [Furthermore](http://www.marienbadmylove.com/):

> By no means does Leach believe his record will stand unchallenged. He is 
>   hedging his bet by also challenging the records for:
>
> - longest word. Also 
>     called "the holy Jah," the 4.4-million-letter noun is a coinage of words from 
>     the world's faiths and means "god within."
> - longest sentence (3 million 
>     words).
> - longest book title (6,700 words)..

Comment: Exactly, that's what I noticed! But did he leave a source list or bibliography of some kind? I never found that part about his possible mental illness, if it is correct, I guess it's just another Charlie Day style collage of crazy ranting? I wonder about the sources because elsewhere (an interview, I lost the url), he seems to mention that he is mainly copying from years of his own writings

Comment: @HenryStone I checked as well as I could in the book files that are available online, and there doesn't seem to be any list of which books he copied from. Regarding the rumours about the author, I just found [this list of questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQuKT.png) (check out the last few!) *in the book itself* (end of part 1 [here](http://www.marienbadmylove.com/download-marienbad-my-love.html)).

Comment: Thanks you! I will dive into those!